# How can I create routes between two separate LANs

Tags: local-area-network, route, traffic, asus

I have a ASUS RT-AC66U with merlin firmware, how can i create a connection between 2 different subnets, whitout using Vlan's ?

My Server subnet is 10.10.1.0  255.0.0.0.0

Asus router and client subnet is 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0

is it necessary to have a second router, to make this work ?

Comment: What is the server plugged into at the moment?

Comment: The Asus router.. I'm running it on a Intel NUC as a host, so there is only one NIC

Comment: Give the router a secondary up address in 10.10.1.0/24. My guess is it will just route with no more setup needed, assuming it has secondary IP options. (But why do you even have separate subnets in such a small setup?)

Comment: I've just gave the servers an IP in the 192.168.1.0 range.. i guess i will need another router, and then create ad static route between the 2 routers.. well mainly because i want to isolate Servers from clients, to have a test lab.. my router does not have an secondary IP option, not that i know of.

Comment: Oh, I see. You don't have the server on 10.10.1.0 but you want to have that. Merlin is openwrt based, and openwrt supports multiple IPs on an interface - e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/20475941 . Although you won't really have "isolation" if it's all on the same physical LAN (but then, you wouldn't have much isolation if they were separate and had routes from one to the other without a firewall).

Comment: Thanks, I've decided to keep it all on the same network, until i get a second router :)